# Void values on CSV header - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I get values from header that have one of it void, eg:

[image: V]

I want to get the last column value in a select... (THIS VALUE)

Thank you in advice.

Comment: what are the code you are using ? what have you tried for now

Comment: I just want a simple querie that get the last column SELECT --- FROM table

Comment: I cannot see images , if you provide example then i might help you

Comment: I really dont know how to get this value... I dnt know what images do you want... SELECT header1,header2.... FROM table??  I just want, how to call this columns and get the values inside in SQLldr or Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

If the name does not exist how about referring to the column id/number instead of the name?